# configure: error: avahi development headers not found

Tags: avahi

i can't install avahi

### error is:

```
checking for AVAHI... yes
checking avahi-client/client.h usability... yes
checking avahi-client/client.h presence... yes
checking for avahi-client/client.h... yes
checking avahi-glib/glib-malloc.h usability... no
checking avahi-glib/glib-malloc.h presence... no
checking for avahi-glib/glib-malloc.h... no
checking for avahi_client_new in -lavahi-client... yes
configure: error: 
avahi development headers not found.
Use --disable-avahi if you do not need avahi (Bonjour) support.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need additionally libavahi development packages. Without knowing what you try to compile I can only give you a list of available packages. Check [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libavahi+dev&searchon=names).

But I believe, you need `libavahi-glib-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libavahi-glib-dev
```

The missing header file `avahi-glib/glib-malloc.h` is in this package.

Comment: this my question too.i don't know

Comment: As I said: `sudo apt-get install libavahi-glib-dev`

Answer (score 0):

This was what I needed:

```
libavahi-client-dev
libavahi-core-dev
```

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Avahi comes installed in recent versions of Ubuntu.